# JavaScript print array to id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print a array to a particular id in my page. I have the array print out just fine but cannot figure out how to get it to print to that id.

This Prints what i want out:

```
for(var i=0;i<playerCards.length;i++){
    document.write('<img src="images/cards/card-' + playerCards[i] + '.jpg" width="58" height="79" alt="playercards" /> ');
}
```

I'm trying to get it to work like this:

```
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML="THE ABOVE LOOP";
```

I have tried combining to two and moving things around but cant seem to figure out how to print it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = '';
for(var i = 0; i < playerCards.length; i++){
    str += '<img src="images/cards/card-' + playerCards[i] + '.jpg" width="58" height="79" alt="playercards" />';
}

document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: i cant get this to work. It wont even print out str in a document.write

Comment: @JohnAyers, how do you include a script?

Comment: @JohnAyers That's because your code is executing immediately (during the parsing of the HTML code). You have to put the JavaScript code inside a DOMContentLoaded handler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i was trying to run the script before the html had even been added!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
document.getElementById( 'player' ).innerHTML = playerCards.map(function ( card ) {
    return '<img src="images/cards/card-' +card + '.jpg" width="58" height="79" alt="playercards"> ';
}).join( '' );
```

Note that, in order to be able to select the `#player` element, you have to execute this code *after* the DOM is ready by putting it inside a "DOMContentLoaded" event handler.